# Photoshop can't resolve fonts set on the same version on OSX

Tags: windows, macos, fonts, adobe-photoshop

On an OSX computer with Photoshop 2014 a font is set.

That same font (literally the same ttf file) is installed on a Windows 7 64bit computer with the same version of Photoshop.

But every time opening the file a message "can't resolve font xyz" pops up and the font is not even listed as a substitute.

Why can't it resolve the exact same font?

Comment: Are you able to use the font in Photoshop in a new document? When Photoshop doesn't resolve the font issue, are you able to select the text and make the text that font? Are you able to use this font in other programs on Windows? Have you tried reinstalling the font and other file types of the font if available?

Comment: Yes I can use the same font in the exact same document by just going to the text with that font and selecting it from the list of fonts (where you can find it). It gives a message before that it can't resolve that font and then there is the normal list of fonts containing that font missing.
I tried all font types available no difference.